# How to show that $f(S) \subset Y $ is dense, when $f$ is continuous and surjective, and $S \subset X$ is dense in $X$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d_x)$ and $(Y,d_y)$ be metric spaces. Furthermore, let $f:X \to Y$ be surjective and continuous. Furthermore: $S \subset X$ is dense in X.

Question: How to prove that $f(S) \subset Y$ is dense in Y?

I wrote down the definitions of *continuity*:

$\forall x \in X, \forall a \in \mathbb{R} :  \exists \delta > 0 $ such that $\forall \epsilon > 0 : |x-a| < \delta \implies |(f(x) - f(a) | < \epsilon , $

and of $S \subset X$ being *dense in X*: 
$ \bar{S} = \{ x \in X | \forall \epsilon > 0 : \exists y \in S $ such that $d(x,y) < \epsilon \} = X $,

and of $f$ being *surjective*:
$\forall p \in Y : \exists x \in X : f(x) = p $.

Using these definitions, I tried to prove: 
$\overline{f(S)} = \{ p \in Y | \forall \epsilon ' > 0 : \exists z \in f(S) $ such that $d(p,z) < \epsilon ' \} = Y.$

I couldn't figure it out, though. I tried proving this by contradiction, but to no avail. Could you please help me out?

Comment: You need the additional assumption that X is compact.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in translating "dicht" from Dutch to English. It should be "dense"!

Comment: It becomes very easy once you have proven that a function is continuous if and only if $f(\overline A)\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$ for every subset $A$ of $X$. By the way, the result is true for arbitrary topological spaces and continuous surjective maps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that in a metric space the closure of a set is the set of limits of all sequences. In particular a set $A$ is dense in a space $X$ iff for any $x \in X$ there is a sequence $a_n \in A$ such that $a_n \rightarrow x$.

Hint: Let $y \in Y$. Then $y = f(x)$ for some $x \in X$. Now think about how to use the fact that $S$ is dense in $X$.

Edit: Since $S$ is dense in $X$ there exists a sequence $s_n \in S$ such that $s_n \rightarrow x$. Can you now find a sequence in $f(S)$ that tends to $y = f(x)$? (Remember, $f$ is continuous!)

Edit 2: To prove this using epsilon delta methods, take any $y \in Y$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. $f$ is surjective so $\exists x \in X$ such that $f(x) = y$. Since $f$ is continuous, $\exists\delta > 0$ such that $d_X(x,z) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x),f(z)) < \epsilon$. Since $S$ is dense in $X$ there exists some $x_0 \in S$ such that $d_X(x,x_{0}) < \delta$. Hence $d_Y(f(x),f(x_{0})) < \epsilon$ and $f(x_0) \in f(S)$. As such $f(S)$ must be dense in $Y$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess this probably shouldn't be very difficult but I just can't see it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MaxMuller No problem, I just extended the answer!

Comment: "In particular a set $A$ is closed..." Shouldn't you be changing "closed" to "dense" there?

Comment: @MaxMuller I've actually used a different (but equivalent) characterisation of dense sets to what you used in the question. This means that we can avoid having to get into the details of using epsilons and deltas. If you like, I can add another part to the answer proving it with epsilons and deltas.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff It certainly should be, thank you very much!

Comment: @MaxMuller I've added in an epsilon delta proof to my answer. There's a lot more to it than there is to the original proof, but it doesn't rely on knowing the alternative definition of dense sets. Thinking about it, this should probably be what I wrote in the first place, since showing that the other condition for a set to be dense is the same as the on you gave is not a trivial result. (Although it's not THAT hard, and I encourage you to try and prove it when you're a little happier with the material!) I hope this helps, let me know if something needs clarifying!

Answer (score 3):

Another characterisation of $S$ being dense in a metric space $X$ is the following:

> for all $x \in X$ and all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $y \in S$ with $d(x,y) < \epsilon$.

Given $v \in Y$ and $\epsilon > 0$, by surjectivity there is an $x \in X$ with $f(x) = v$, and by continuity there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $d_Y ( f(x) , f(y) ) < \epsilon$ for all $y \in X$ with $d_X (x,y) < \delta$. As $S$ is dense in $X$ there must be a $y \in S$ such that $d_X (x,y) < \delta$. But now $f(y) \in f [ S ]$ and by choice of $\delta$, $d_Y ( v , f(y) ) < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=f(y)$ and $\epsilon>0$. We want to find $z\in f(S): d(y,z)<\epsilon$.
Since $f$ is continues exists $\delta>0: d(x,w)<\delta \Longrightarrow d(f(x),f(w))<\epsilon.$ 
Now use the fact that $S$ is dense in $X$ to find $w\in S:d(x,w)<\delta.$

Answer (score 1):

Continuous functions preserve limits. Take a point in $x\in X$, and a sequence in $(x_n)\in S$ converging to $x$. Then $(y_n=f(x_n))\in f(S)$ will converge to $f(x)\in Y$ (by surjectivity).

**ADD** Recall that in metric spaces, we can characterize density in the following manner:

> A subset $D$ is dense on $X$ if for every $x\in X$ there exists a sequence of points $d_n\in D$ such that $d_n\to x$.

Comment: Why do we require that $f$ be onto for the image of a dense subset to be dense?

Comment: @TaylorRendon The result is false otherwise. Consider a constant function.

Answer (score 0):

To show that $f(S)$ is dense in $Y$, we show that $f(S)\cap V\neq\emptyset$ for all non-empty open subsets $V$ of $Y$. By way of contradiction, suppose there is a non-empty open set $V\subseteq Y$ such that $f(S)\cap V=\emptyset.$ The preimage of $\emptyset$ under any function is $\emptyset$, so $$\begin{align}\emptyset &= f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\cap V\bigr)\\ &= \bigl\{x\in X:f(x)\in f(S)\cap V\bigr\}\\ &= \bigl\{x\in X:f(x)\in f(S)\bigr\}\cap\bigl\{x\in X:f(x)\in V\bigr\}\\ &= f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)\cap f^{-1}(V).\end{align}$$ We necessarily have $S\subseteq f^{-1}\bigl(f(S)\bigr)$, so it follows that $$S\cap f^{-1}(V)=\emptyset.$$ Now, $S$ is dense in $X$, and $f^{-1}(V)$ is open, as the preimage of the open set $V$ under the continuous map $f$, so we must have $f^{-1}(V)=\emptyset.$ But $V$ is a non-empty subset of $Y$ and $f$ maps surjectively to $Y$, so we have our contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Direct proof: let $U \subset Y$ be open and non-empty. Since $f$ is surjective, $f^{-1}(U) \subset X$ is non-empty, and open since $f$ is continuous so it preserves open-ness.

Now $S$ is dense in $X$ so $S \cap f^{-1}(U)$ is non-empty. So $\exists x \in f^{-1}(U) \cap S$ s.t. $f(x) \in U$, i.e. $\exists x \in S$ s.t. $f(x) \in U \implies f(S) \cap U$ is non-empty.

$\therefore f(S)$ is dense in $Y$.